# How to set Minecraft server port from the CLI?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can't seem to find an up-to-date and clear answer on this. I just want to run the Minecraft server JAR on a different port than the default 25565.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the port in the server.properties-file. You can find this file in the same directory as your server.jar is in. Edit this file like this: `server-port=<new-port>` (e.g. `server-port=1337` to run the server on port 1337).

You can find a detailed documentation about the server.properties-file and the affected property here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties

If you really want to change the port from cli you can use Bukkit and pass an argument `-p=<new-port>` to launch the server on a different port. It also overrides the `server-port`-property in the server.properties-file. (Source: [CraftBukkit Source Code](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/Main.java#L51)) Example: `java -jar bukkit.jar -p=1337`.

Hope it helps. :)