# What application type and protocol do I use for port forwarding on 2WIRE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting

I want to host a simple Minecraft server on my home laptop. I am at the port forwarding stage and I need to know whether to select TCP, UDP, or make one for both, open on the same port. Also, what application type do I use: DirectX Game or PPTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you need to port forward [TCP 25565](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server#Firewalling.2C_NATs_and_external_IP_addresses). No UDP required for this game.

You can change this port by using `server-port=<new-port>` as outlined in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148864/how-to-set-minecraft-server-port-from-cli?rq=1).

As for what type of application, you need to ask 2Wire.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to boot up the server with no problems and all my friends are able to connect.